# Unable to preview a pdf attachment in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, email, pdf, outlook-on-the-web

Whenever I receive a PDF attachment in an email using Outlook Web App for Exchange 2019, I have the option to preview the file, but when I click it this is what shows up in the preview screen:

[image]

Clicking open just downloads it to be opened in Adobe. Adobe is currently set to the default PDF viewer, I have tried switching it to chrome as well.

Firefox works without issues

Changing AlwaysOpenPDFExternally reg key

Chrome version: Version 120.0.6099.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Anyone have this issue or know a fix?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting-like questions are off-topic on Web Applications Stack Exchange.